# Solr: changing the data directory in Windows

Tags: windows, solr, configuration

I'm trying to change my Solr core's data directly away from the default 'data' directory under the instance directory.  I'm using an absolute path because my Solr core's instance and conf directories are buried elsewhere (inside my GitHub directory).  I thought it would be as easy as specifying this in core.properties:

```
dataDir=C:\foo\bar\my_new_data_directory
```

Inside the 'my_new_data_directory' directory are the following Solr directories:

```
- index
- tlog
```

I'm using Windows and am getting the following error when starting up Solr:

```
ERROR - 2014-01-17 12:40:34.578; org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer; Unable to create core: collection1
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:680)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:625)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:557)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:592)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:271)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:263)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.core.StandardDirectoryFactory.normalize(StandardDirectoryFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.solr.core.DirectoryFactory.getDataHome(DirectoryFactory.java:246)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:677)
    ... 13 more
```

It looks like I'm not specifying the file path properly.  How is it supposed to be specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant, but the only way I could get this to work properly was to hard code the full path into solrconfig.xml like this:

```
<dataDir>C:/foo/bar/my_new_data_directory/core1</dataDir>
```

**UPDATE (2014-02-14)**

I've realized that I can combine a couple of approaches to get the desired result.

When starting up Solr, I can include this parameter:

```
data.dir=C:/foo/bar/my_new_data_directory/
```

Then in solrconfig.xml, I can prefix my data directory with the parameter set during startup:

```
<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}core1</dataDir>
```

This will set the data directory to: C:/foo/bar/my_new_data_directory/core1

With this technique, I can support multiple cores without having the hard code the full path in solrconfig.xml:

```
C:/foo/bar/my_new_data_directory/core1
C:/foo/bar/my_new_data_directory/core2
```

Comment: Additionally, you can set the data location of a single core by adding a line like `dataDir=C\:\\Data\\my_new_data_dir` (note the escaping!) to that core's `core.properties` file.

Answer (score 2):

I stopped using core.properties a couple of versions ago as variable substitution was not working properly, but I can do this in sorl.xml:

```
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" dataDir="c:\temp\data" />
```

and the index path gets properly picked up.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but be careful that as of version 5.0, the presence of the cores tag in solr.xml will generate an error on startup: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%204.4%20and%20beyond

Answer (score 1):

I think this needs to be specified in tomcat (or equivalent) like this:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsolr.data.dir=C:\foo\bar\my_new_data_directory"
```

The solrconfig.xml looks for it like this:

```
<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>
```

I also noticed some people doing like this:

Open up the solrconfig.xml

```
<dataDir>${solr.data.dir}</dataDir>
by following 
<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:/opt/solr/example/solr/data}</dataDir>
```

Comment: -Dsolr.data.dir=C:\foo\bar\my_new_data_directory works, but it seems that this becomes the data directory for all of the cores, and if I have more than one core, I get errors.  Is there a way to get Solr to look into the subfolders of the data folder to find the data for each core?  Example: C:\foo\bar\core1 and C:\foo\bar\core2

I tried the <dataDir> technique to try and specify subfolders for each core, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hardcode the core name in the path, you could use the built-in `${solr.core.name}` variable, which should automatically get set to the core name.

I use that for generalizing some master/slave replication paths across solr instances and cores and it works well.

I also use it for a suggester index which doesn't seem to default to the same data directory as the main index for the core (I'd call that a bug).  So we hardcode the index dir for that suggester with something like this (this is an optional value for the infix analyzer but the concept applies anywhere in the `solrconfig.xml`):

```
<str name="indexPath">C:/indexes/${country}/${solr.core.name}/data/suggest_tag</str>
```

The `${country}` value is created in `solrcore.properties`, e.g. `country=US`, so we can generalize this setup across different solr instances.  That might give you even more ideas of what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax of `solrcore.properties`/`core.properties` is:

```
solr.data.dir=/path/foo/here
```

or:

```
solr.data.dir=C:\\foo\\bar\\data
```

where on Windows I think you should use the double backslashes as above.

If this won't work, the error:

> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

could be potentially related to [SOLR-4810](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4810) bug which was fixed already.